# How to get the current DataGrid row selected in extended selection mode?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `dataGrid` with the selection mode in extended, so I can select many rows.

I have a style trigger, with a multi-value converter, to set the background color of the row according to some conditions.

Well, in my probes, I pass three parameters: `ItemsSource`, `SelectedItems` and `selectedItem`. I notice the following behavior:

When I select the first row, `ItemsSource` has all the rows of the `dataGrid`. This is correct. `SelectedItems` has 0 items and `selectedItem` is null. However, without do nothing, the code enter by second time in the converter, in this case `SelectedItem` is the item selected in the `dataGrid`, but `SelectedItems` has no items.

When I select the second row, `SelectedItems` has one item, the first selected row of the `dataGrid`, and `selectedItem` has the first row too. In this case the code does not enter by second time in the converter.

When I select the third row, `SelectedItems` has two items, the first and the second row selected, but not the third. `SelectedItem` has the first row selected.

So I see that `SelectedItem` alway has the first row selected and `SelectedItems` has the n-1 selected rows.

But how can I know what is the current selected row? The new row?

Comment: Clean up the question.  E.G. "However, without do nothing, the code enter by second time in the converter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"></DataGrid>
```

Your selectionUnit must be FullRow .I hope this will help.

Comment: Yes, I have setted this two options in this way.